# Generate uuid from BT Mac address iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I am building an app with BLE device. I need some help create UUID from my BT Mac Address.

I read a little and understand that in IOS (above IOS 7) I can't get the BT MAC address. 
I am trying to scan a QR code with Mac Address and create a UUID that will match the UUID I get from the device scan.

MAC address format: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UUID was generated by iOS system. Every different iOS device generate different uuid for same peripheral.
same iOS device but different application has same uuid for peripheral.
So we can't provide or handle peripheral uuid.

If u add mac address in peripheral service data then u will create uuid from mac address.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to obtain the MAC address through Core Bluetooth and the algorithm that Apple uses to generate k`CBPeripheral` identifiers is not documented (and doesn't generate a fixed identifier for a given device anyway, as you have found).

You could include your own identifier either in the advertising data for your peripheral or as a characteristic value. This would allow your app to identify a particular peripheral.